# Is it safe to delete iCloud cache directory?

Tags: macos, icloud

It is safe to delete the following directory?

> /Users/me/Library/Containers/com.apple.icloud.drive.fileprovider/Data/Library/Application Support/iCloudDrive/account-XXXXXXXXXX/session/cache/unlink

It seems that this directory has huge amounts of files, and due to that my mac cannot install Catalina, which takes 17GB of disk space.

Or if deleting causes any problems, what problem is it?